# Fixed element not breaking out of transformed, relative parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a fixed nested element which is `position:fixed`. It's immediate parent is `position:relative` with a translation transformation `transform : translate(2px,2px)`; applied to it.

But because of this transformation applied to the parent, the nested fixed element is unable to break out of the parent and position itself relative to the window instead

Is this the intended behaviour or perhaps its a bug? It behaves the same way on chrome, safari and firefox.

Wondering how can i break the nested fixed element out if the relative parent has transformation applied.

The code snippet i have attached is a simplified version of the actual one im working on.

```css
.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:beige;
}

.relative {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:skyblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  top : 100px; left: 100px;
  
  /* this is causing the 'bug'*/
  transform : translate(2px,2px);
}

.fixed-2 {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:gray;
  top: 0; 
  left : 0;
  transform:translate(100px, 0px);
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  Fixed Element
  
  <div class="relative">
    Relative Element
    <div class="fixed fixed-2">
    Why is this fixed element position relative to its parent and not the window?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

alternatively, i also have this replicated in codepen. https://codepen.io/farisk/pen/zYvXvox

Answer (score -1):

Basically - the position of a `fixed` element will be relative to the first parent with `relative` rule, so this is expected.

Not sure why you use transform to position elements, and not sure what is the outcome you want in your more complicated code but you can remove the `relative` from the parent and set the top/left of the fixed position where you want it to be.

Or, just add the fixed div as a child of the body, so you won't need to change the css of other elements you already have.

```css
.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:beige;
}

.relative {
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:skyblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  top : 100px; left: 100px;
}

.fixed-2 {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:gray;
  top: 30px;
  left : 30px;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  Fixed Element
  
  <div class="relative">
    Relative Element
    <div class="fixed fixed-2">
    Why is this fixed element position relative to its parent and not the window?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the positions will be dynamic. so if i used your method, then i have calculate the offset manually each time. as mentioned. it is a simplified version of the code im working with

Comment: i dont think fixed elements are relative to first relative element. i think youre talking about absolute.

i have the transformation to the relative parent for a reason which i can't explain here

Comment: Just check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position "An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position value is absolute or fixed. The top, right, bottom, and left properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing block. (The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.)"